# How to let user know when UIStepper value is incremented or decremented

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistepper

I have tried to search for the answer but unable to find one, I am successfully using UIStepper in my `ViewController` with increment and decrement values to be used as required but i want to show user when stepper is tapped with an animation so user can see it is pressed, any suggestion?

please do not share code on how to increment decrement values, also i know user can see the incremented and decremented value being changed when UIStepper is pressed, I am concerned with the animation or anything else which user can see when stepper is pressed.

Comment: You can make your custom with two UIButtons and making the button scale in/out animated whenever user taps on it.

Comment: rajan can you please share the sample code for the assistance.

Comment: if clicked, values are gonna increase/ increase, which is clear indication that stepper is clicked...